# Storing image path in MySQL vs HTTP GET with <img src="" onError="">

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, database

I’m designing a Listing site, wherein each user can upload multiple images (<10) and they are stored in files on the server. When UI sends AJAX request to backend I’m not sending any image info in the JSON response. Rather I’m deriving the image path from the User ID itself. Reason being, not wanted to put an overhead of storing image info/path in DB (MySQL) for faster DB search. So I'm displaying images using the following:

```
<img src="..." onError="defaultImage(this);" />
function defaultImage(source) {
    source.src = 'blank.png';
    source.onerror = null; 
    return false;
}
```

So far so good. But the problem is when I look at the browser console, it’s printing

> GET url [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 5ms]

I'm sending 20 user/listings per AJAX request and also listings are auto-loaded while scrolling, so the entire console gets flooded with these errors.
Now my question is, is it OK to have these errors or should I store the image path info in DB instead and display only the images having valid path. My only concern is adding an extra column to store image info might have performance impact on the SQL query, so I tried to store as less columns/info as possible in the main Table (which acts as index for listings) to have the search as fast as possible. Or, is there any way to hide these errors from browser console?

Comment: can you provide an example image link? remove the `onError` attribute for a min and post the `img` tag

Comment: The impact of storing filenames/filepaths in the db is negligible on properly indexed tables. I've developed sites that house hundreds of millions of photos, with each path to said photo stored in a `photos` table, along with a foreign key back to the main table's ID. Queries fire, photo filepaths are retrieved, all in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use this string as source url for image to avoid requests to server (and 404 error responses too)

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7
```

Comment: Thank you Nick, but where am I suppose to add the path, I mean in <img id="profile" src="/images/uploads/1/profile.jpg" />

Comment: I got that, echo base64_encode(file_get_contents()), but this won't wok for me because I'm using JavaScript to populate the images

Comment: My code is minimal blank image. You could do like that `<img src="data:image/... my string here..." data-path="/images/uploads/1/profile.jpg" />`, and later when you need to display real image take a value from `data-path` attribute, create url and put it to `src` attribute

Comment: but then the 404 will be logged later when I put the url in src attribute, if the url is not available. I think it's just delays the browser console logging

Comment: please clear for me why you need to put wrong url to src?

Comment: for the very fact, UI doesn't know if the URL exists, as in the question I mentioned back-end is not sending any image info, it's derived from the User ID itself, it's for performance reason

Answer (score 0):

Storing the paths (and not the images themselves) in the database is the good way to go.

I don't really know how you are currently storing images, but a table like that would make sense:

```
+---------+---------+-------------+---------------+
|image_id | user_id |  image_path | date_uploaded |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 1       | 1       | /img/xxx.png|  31|07|2016   |
| 2       | 1       | /img/yyy.png|  31|07|2016   |
| 3       | 5       | /img/zzz.png|  31|07|2016   |
+---------+---------+-----------------------------+
```

You would have to check manually that the user has less than 10 images when he tries to upload a new one.

Then, when you want to retrieve all the images of an user, you can make an ajax call to your backend, who would run a query like

```
SELECT image_path FROM images
JOIN users ON users.user_id = images.user_id
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks Christopher for your reply. I wanted to avoid Join, because there could be millions of users firing the query and per user there will be at least 5 AJAX request per second. So, I want to keep the table as lite as possible and it has got spatial column as well

Comment: Why would you need 5 ajax request per second? Also, you can dramatically improve performance by creating an index on the `user_id` field in `user`

Comment: well, I don't need 5, but the end user might fire, because it's a map based search, as user moves the map AJAX gets fired, so imagine how fast/frequently one can move the google map, yes I do have indexes: PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
SPATIAL INDEX `location_index` (`location`)

Comment: Maybe you can also have some prefetching, then? Instead of only loading the images that are in the current viewport of the map, load all of them in a range of several times the viewport frame. Just some random thoughts

Comment: @surz - Will there really be "millions of users" or is that just wishful thinking? If you're expecting millions of users on the site at any given time, then you'd better start looking into alternative methods to serve your resources, ie. MongoDB/Redis, Elasticsearch, CDNs, etc, etc, etc. But if not, don't worry so much about JOIN's. When properly indexed they are faster than the blink of an eye.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting the src by default and using OnError to generate the default image path using a function you should just add some default css for any img tag that doesn't have a src attribute. Then keep OnError for images that actually fail to load. This ultimately reduces the total amount of requests made to a minimum.

`img:not([src]) {
  // Default Image CSS
}`